# Python: plot a dict of keys and values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot an x, y graph of a data dictionary (key and values).
The key is a datetime value.
Each value for key contains an object, ie my_data, that has attributes - name, count, totalCount

On the graph, on the x-axis, I would like to use the key (datetime)
On the y-axis, I would like to multi plot the my_data attributes, a separate point for each attribute - my_data.name, my_data.count my_data.totalCount

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please share a minimal reproducible sample code and data to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I would use dictionaries inside dictionary. So parent dictionary has datetime has a key, inside is dictionary with keys from 1 to 3 representing attributes of the object and values are the attribute values. So on the plot I would just put the attribute values as text.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what I had in mind for the solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython
# --------------------
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['font.size'] = 20
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import datetime
# -------------------------------------
# ==================================================
N = 5
dates = [datetime.datetime(2022,11,10)+ii*datetime.timedelta(days=1) for ii in range(5)];
count = 5+5*np.random.random(N,)
name = ['Name'+str(ii).rjust(2,'0') for ii in range(5)]
totcount = 10+2*np.random.random(N,)
# --------------------------------------------------
plotdata = {dates[ii]:{1:round(count[ii],1),2:name[ii],3:round(totcount[ii],1)} for ii in range(len(dates))}
# --------------------------------------------------
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10));ax = fig.add_subplot(111);
for dval,pdict in plotdata.items():
    for kv,vv in pdict.items():
        ax.text(dval,kv,str(vv),ha='left',va='bottom')
        ax.plot(dval,kv,ms=10,color='k');
ax.set_ylim((0,5)) # to squeeze more together the values
ax.set_yticklabels('') # to remove y-axis text
plt.show()
```